# Font problems; Hebrew with KOMA document classes; error message

Tags: fonts, xetex, koma-script, hebrew

I am using XeLaTeX for writing texts in Hebrew. Now I have been trying to use the KOMA document classes. After applying a few changes (like changing the font used for chapter, section, ... headlines to a fonts that also contains Hebrew) everything seems to be working very nicely, except for one minor annoyance:

I am getting the following error messages:

```
! Package polyglossia Error:
The current roman font does not contain the Hebrew script!
Please define \hebrewfont with \newfontfamily.
See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
```

The errors refer to lines where new sections are being defined. The funny thing is that this error message even occurs when the text is entirely in Hebrew and contains no Latin or any other non-Hebrew characters whatsoever.

So, does anyone know what the problem is and how to get rid of it?

Here is a short example:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[14pt]{scrbook}
\pagestyle{empty}
\TeXXeTstate=1
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Adobe Hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Scale=0.80,Script=Hebrew]{Adobe Hebrew}

\setkomafont{section}{\hebrewfont}

\begin{document}

\section{מה הבעיה?}

\section{יש פתרון?}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first: I doubt a bit that you actually want to use `\setkomafont`. This will also reset the *size* of font in the section title to the normal size. Better use `\addtokomafont`.

At second: The source of your problem is that – regardless what you do with `\setkomafont` –inside the `\section` command the KOMA-classes issue a `\sffamily`. So temporarly there is a switch to this font and as the active language is hebrew and your current `\sffamily` font  doesn't know the hebrew script you get an error. You can remove the `\sffamily` in the section titles by redefining `\sectfont`.

```
\renewcommand*\sectfont{\normalcolor\bfseries}
```

But imho the better solution is (as hebrew is your main language) is to set the main fonts to fonts that know the script:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{scrbook}
\pagestyle{empty}
\TeXXeTstate=1
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ezra SIL}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ezra SIL}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Ezra SIL}

\begin{document}
\section{abc}

abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Now everything works perfectly. But anyway, I still don't quite understand why my override with `\setkomafont{section}{\hebrewfont}` worked and still resulted in an error (at least this seems obvious now, since `\setsansfont` was not set properly). So, I guess, it was just a half-override.

Comment: `\section` contains two font commands: `\sectfont` which is used in all other sectioning commands too and which contains the problematic `\sffamily`and `\size@section` which is specific to `\section`. Your `\setkomafont` changes the second. Btw: as I just realized you can redefine `\sectfont` also through `\setkomafont` by using `\setkomafont{disposition}{...}`